# User create by Kibana can't not sign in {"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I'm having a problem with New User created by Kibana (using user "elastic"). This is the order i did.

I'm using ELK for 7.5.1 version

1. First, i enable security in `elasticsearch.yml` by added `xpack.security.enabled: true`
2. Second, at `kibana.yml` i edit `elasticsearch.username` = "elasctic" and `elasticsearch.password` is my set up password
3. I start service elasticsearch and kibana.
4. I sign Kibana link with user "elastic"
5. I create role "test" like the picture
   [image]
6. I create user "test001" with role "test" like picture below
   [image]
7. I try to login with my new create user but fail.

   {"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}

So how can I fix it? or somethings i know about user is wrong ? I want to make some authen with the Security function.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your user should work at http level (using curl for example) but if you want to use kibana, add the kibana_user role too. It is required to use kibana.

Have a look on the docs about [build in roles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-roles.html) and [kibana authorization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.5/xpack-security-authorization.html) for more details.